# How to disable https for tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, https, liferay

I didn't do any change but today, after turning on my computer, I'm not able to start Liferay portal...I keep getting

```
SEVERE: Catalina.start:
LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Catalina"; Protocol handler start fail
ed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Martin\.keystore
```

I think I didn't do any change there, therefore I really don't know, how to fix it... I will appreciate any advice.

I don't want any HTTPS for tomcat - I just want to start my AS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your tomcat home directory and find file `server.xml` (it usualy located in conf folder). There you'll need to find https connector configuration. It looks like this:

```
<Connector port="8443" ... SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" ... />
```

Comment out this configuration line.

Comment: Well...this seem sto be solving the problem with the missing keystore file..nevertheless even when the portal seems to be running, I keep getting 404 while I try to access any site... (-_-) Ane the weirest thing is, that it worked yesterday before I went to bed...damn you, computers x-)

Comment: @Dworza What port is configured for your plain text connector? It's probably the topic for another question though

Comment: it was because of expired database password

Answer (score 1):

You'll find a Connector reference in `conf/server.xml`, which most likely is pointing to the keystore you name. Deactivate that connector and you should be fine